# winfr ignores folder location (windows file recovery)

Tags: windows-10, file-recovery

winfr seems pretty simple, it runs / recovers files, just not the correct folder. Below is what I am entering, but it ignores my requested location and just starts recovering files from my documents folder. Any idea why is this happening?

I deleted the whole folder "internal" by mistake, and I want everything in that folder back.

```
winfr c: D: /regular /n \__Projects\V\109148\internal\ *
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.  It seems to recovery everything except what I'm asking for.